# not unattractive VS. not an attractive

Tags: grammar, adverbs

*A not unattractive girl is usually used to describe quite an attractive girl.

Not an attractive girl is definitely an unattractive girl.*

Would you tell me more about these? or how do you use these? and if they are correct?

More over, are they informal?

Answer (score 2):

Many adjectives have antonyms, but that doesn't mean that all associated nouns fall into one category or the other.

For example, there are expensive cars, and there are cheap cars. But there are cars that fall into the middle of that spectrum, and wouldn't be categorized as expensive or cheap.

Take a look at the set of all cars:

[image]

A "not expensive car" is in the blue/green area, and a "not cheap car" is in the green/yellow area.

You can change "cars" to "girls", and "price" to "attractiveness", and get the answer to your specific question.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Finally, would you tell me where/ in which situation you would rather use:
A not unattractive girl 

Not an attractive girl

Comment: As a father of three daughters, I don't talk much about "not unattractive girls." I suppose if you were setting up a friend on a blind date, and the woman he'd be dating was not a stunner, but wasn't ugly either, you might say, "Well, she's not an unattractive girl," and then go on to talk about less superficial characteristics, like her sense of humor, intellect, or personality.

Comment: Thanks. But, would you more readily explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I would use **attractive, unattractive or good looking**. The *nots* are only confusing the meaning and makes it sound like you are uncertain. **Good looking** is a good middle of the road term, as it does not really imply either attractive or unattractive.